# Can't publish GitBook, the error message is vague and without detail

Tags: gitbook

I'm trying to publish something that I've written to my GitBook page using the GitBook GUI on Ubuntu 14. To do that I'm just going to book > publish as > book-name

But this error appears:

> This doesn't happen often, but it looks like something is broken. Hitting the back button and trying again might be your best bet. If that doesn't work you can head back to the homepage.
>
> There might be more information on our status page which is reporting All Systems Operational.

The book names already been set up as a thing on the website, and I'm signed in on both programme and website.

I'm not sure what I'm meant to do.

Comment: I think it will be helpful if put the error message (verbatim) into your post.

Comment: cheers @DavidTansey, I've updated the OP... not sure whats to be gleaned from it TBH

Comment: @DavidTansey - any ideas following the update?

Comment: WOW -- Not much of an error message is it?  Take a peek at the following posts which are only 10 days old: https://github.com/GitbookIO/editor/issues/185  Please check it out -- I've got a feeling that it may provide an answer for your problem.

Comment: @DavidTansey no ha, it was a bit vague.... Yes - that's helped a lot thank you... All I had to do was name the version 0.0.1 instead of 1... I thought there was network / sync / install error or something ha... durrr! stick an answer on and Ill mark it solved:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current GitBook version 1.1.1 (and previous versions) have a bug/issue reported which relates to this error message and its vagueness.

https://github.com/GitbookIO/editor/issues/185

The problem you are experiencing is likely due to an invalid value specified for the `Version` when you try to publish.

Although the publish dialog does provide a hint:
[image]

> Version must be a semver (ex: 0.0.1, 0.4.5, ...)

there is nothing in the error message to help you understand that this `Version` value is source of the error.

If you provide a value for `Version` in the format suggested by the hint in the dialog, I believe you will no longer encounter this error.

Comment: thanks @David Tansey - although on my version of GitBook I didn't have that prompt about the version numbering. It's blank, I think I'd have picked it up else ;) It's working now though, cheers